# Mouse enter work only sometimes afte load the page in Chrome on a SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a web wapplication with some SVG (On Ilustrator).

http://www.calimastudio.es/clientes/mercatenerife/planos/index.php
When you click on "Complejo A", then you can do mouseover on a local (A13,A14 etc) and its turn on blue. It works perfectly on Firefox and Iexplorer, but in Chrome it fails most of time.

The funcion is:

```
function showLocal(id, event) {
  var a;
  a=document.getElementById(id);
  var svgDoc = (a.contentDocument);
  var color_original;
  var fondo_original;

  $('#locales g', svgDoc).on('mouseenter', function(e){   // <-------------
    fondo_original=$(this).find('rect').css('fill');
    color_original_text=$(this).find('text').css('fill');
    color_original=$(this).find('tspan').css('fill');
    fondo_original2=$(this).find('path').css('fill');

    paintLocal($(this), fondo_activo, color_activo);
    $(this).find('path').css('stroke', color_activo);
    $(this).find('path').css('fill', fondo_activo);

    moveWindow(id, e.clientX);
  });

  $('#locales g', svgDoc).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).find('rect').css('fill', fondo_original);
    $(this).find('text').css('fill', color_original_text);
    $(this).find('tspan').css('fill', color_original);
    $(this).find('path').css('stroke', color_borde_libre);
    $(this).find('path').css('fill', fondo_original2);

    $('path', svgDoc).each(function(){
      $(this).css('stroke', color_borde_libre);
      $(this).find('path').css('fill', fondo_original2);
    }
  );
  $('#p3').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

It is called at start under document.ready in http://www.calimastudio.es/clientes/mercatenerife/planos/js/init.js

In the debugger the function shoLocal is always called Ok, but when its failing
the  line

```
$('#locales g', svgDoc).on('mouseenter', function(e){
```

doesn't do a breakpoint, and in the other and, when is working the breakpoint works.

I have no any clue about what to do now. I see the network console on Chrome and it is all ok, also there is any javascript error in the console.

Comment: Note: At the begining the SVG were generated by Inkscape, and it works always ok on Chrome. But they doesn't work on mobile.

Then to solve this problem, we change the software for SVG to Ilustrator by exporting to SVG basic. The mobile problem was solved buy apperars the commented bug.

Comment: Format save in ilustrator: SVG 1.1

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found about this issue, hope will help:

If you want to use mouseenter instead of mouseover. you should know that Chrome, and Safari still haven’t integrated it yet.

you can use mouseover instead but you will need to cancel event bubbles

[image]

[External source](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html)

Comment: But its mean that works sometimes or never?
Because before move to Ilustrator the function works always.
It was no random.

Now it's random. Some times mouseenter works.

Comment: I did:

  $('#locales g', svgDoc).on('mouseover', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
...


And I had the same result. Locals don't turn on blue when refrefhing some time.

Haven't any clue yet.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I call the function after 1 second with:

```
setTimeout(function(){ showLocals(event); }, 1000);
```

Works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and Explorer.

I don't know the exact reason. Looks a Chrome bug.

Thank you for your help Simo.

Note: Lot of time loss. Hope this help to anyone in the future.